# Выводит ошибку ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '', не работает в PyCharm, но работает в онлайн компиляторе

Tags: python, pycharm

```
    gryffindor_score = int(input())
    counter = 0
    while gryffindor_score >= 0:
        sneit = int(input())
        gryffindor_score = gryffindor_score - sneit
        counter += 1
    print(counter)
```

При вводе 200 и 500 выводит данную ошибку:

```
line 4, in <module>
sneit = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Но только в PyCharm, недавно обновил его до версии 2022.1, может проблема в этом

Comment: Нужно обновить PyCharm до 2022.1.2 или включить эмуляцию консоли в терминале PyCharm

Comment: Большое спасибо!